# HTML + CSS hoverable dropdown expands header

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

There is an issue with dropdown, when hover it.
   Instead of normal opening, the dropdown menu expands header.
   Where is an error in the code?
   I wrote this code from example on w3school()[Code example, by which this code is written](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_dropdown_navbar)
   There are also several attempts to do the same:
   [first attempt](https://liveweave.com/bKvNTG)
   [second attempt](https://liveweave.com/ww1Ybn)
   And in all of these attempts i do the same error, but cannot find where 
   exactly.
   Can somebody show where are the errors?

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header, nav {
    background-color: aliceblue;
    color: darkcyan;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: darkcyan;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.active {
    padding-left: 0;
}

a, .dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.dropdown .dropbutton {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: inherit;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    color: black;
    width: auto;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Dropdown Third Version</title>
</head>
<body>

<header>

    <h1>The Homework</h1>

    <nav>

        <a href="" target="" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="hobbies.html" target="_blank">Hobbies</a>
        <a href="third.html" target="_blank">Third Page</a>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbutton">Dropdown</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="">One</a>
                <a href="">Two</a>
                <a href="">Three</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </nav>

</header>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a simple change to position in css:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;----------------------This One
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Use this link to understand: [Difference Between relative and absolute](https://medium.com/@leannezhang/difference-between-css-position-absolute-versus-relative-35f064384c6)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have given `position:relative` in css instead give `position:absolute` for following selector `.inline:hover .dropdown`

```
.inline:hover .dropdown {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: dimgray;
}
```

And one more modification is that for all sub menu you have mentioned the class `dropdown` instead of that under one div which is having class `dropdown`

```
<div class="inline">The Page
            <div class="dropdown">
              <div>One</div>
              <div>Two</div>
              <div>Three</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

here is working example : https://liveweave.com/NpUwOZ

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
position: absolute;
width: auto;
text-align: center;
```

}

***just delete the position line or change position in to absolute***

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to link the CSS file in your HTML code. Make sure you do that first.

Othetwise it won't do anything.